# Script doesnt increase font size randomly for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using following script to increase for size by 1 pixel script works fine when I bind it with `p` element but it increases font size two or three times if I use it with nested div and bind script to `div` element

[example on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WR3Am/2/)

Sample script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//Here we're using jQuery 1.4.2
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  //This is our jQuery code
  //Code to increase our text by 2px
  $('#increaseText').click(function() {
    //Increate the font size by 2px
    $('p').css('font-size', parseInt($('p').css('font-size'))+1);
    $('div').css('font-size', parseInt($('div').css('font-size'))+1);
  });
  //Code to decrease our text by 2px
  $('#decreaseText').click(function() {
    //Decrease the font size by 2px
    $('p').css('font-size', parseInt($('p').css('font-size'))-1);
    $('div').css('font-size', parseInt($('div').css('font-size'))-1);
  });
});
</script>
```

I tried to make this script with element ID then it wont work at all, I would appreciate if this can be fixed. I am not sure or what cases nested div to increase font 2 or 3 times

Comment: `$('p').css('font-size')` returns with 'px' attached to it

Comment: @asifsid88 as long as `parseInt()` is there, it doesn't matter if it ends with 'px'.

Comment: Consider rewording the title. "[...] randomly for some reason" sounds too good to be true.

Answer (score 0):

When are are setting the font-size on your elements, you aren't adding any units. Try fixing up your code to include the units of the font size:

```
$('p').css('font-size', (parseInt($('p').css('font-size'))-1) + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PTy2n/)

```
$('p').css('font-size', '+=1');
```

**Update**

This won't work in jQuery 1.4.2.

For 1.4.2, use

```
ss = parseInt($('p').css('font-size')) + 1 + "px";
$('p').css('font-size', ss);
```